# How to create a fixed button on top of a scrollview in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am looking for a solution to create a button on top of a scrollview that is not moving with the scroll. Everything that I tried so far creates the button either under the scroll or inside.

Here is some of the code.
I am trying to make the MDRaisedButton to be on top of ScrollView and remain in that position even when a user scrolls.

Something like having a tag in HTML with `position: fixed;`

Python:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.list import ImageLeftWidget
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineAvatarListItem


sm = ScreenManager()

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def AddToList(self):
        item = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text='@name', id='id')
        item.add_widget(ImageLeftWidget(source='src/avatars/cropped-Avatar-Round.png'))
        self.ids.container.add_widget(item)
        print("+1")

class MainApp(MDApp):
    info = {}
    def build(self):
        self.root_widget = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root_widget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Kivy:

```
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name:'main_screen'

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "add"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}
        index:10
        on_release:
            root.AddToList()
  
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        index:5
    
        GridLayout:
            index:5
            cols: 1
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            # size_hint: None, None
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_Y: None
            do_scroll_x: False
            id: container
```

Comment: It would be better if you show us your codes so that we could understand your issue better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to the `Button` to be "on top" of the `ScrollView`, you just need to make sure it is drawn after the `ScrollView`. To do that, you can move the `Button` in the `kv` to after the `ScrollView`:

```
<MainScreen>:
    name:'main_screen'

    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        index:5
    
        GridLayout:
            index:5
            cols: 1
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            # size_hint: None, None
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            do_scroll_x: False
            height: self.minimum_height
            id: container
            
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "add"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}
        index:10
        on_release:
            root.AddToList()
```